# Microsoft Access VBA assistance for Here API

Tags: ms-access, vba, here-api

For years I used google maps to calculate travel time and distance for sales routes. Using MS Access database table for locations and a little form that a user could select addresses and number a route sequence.

However, this data is not freely accessible anymore.

I used to send google maps a simple string that contained a starting address and an ending address and I would get back a data string that would, among other things, contain the travel time and distance.

I would like to obtain a similar result with Here.

What I don't see at the Here site is any VBA guidance so I can write a callable module, in Access, that returns simple travel time and distance.

Comment: I suggest you look at  their site  https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-constructing.html   which shows what the outbound message looks like.

Comment: Added Here API tag. Removed opinion / irrelevant information. Removed pointers to other services to avoid opinion based answers. Changed structure of alineae to make question clearer.

Comment: It is advisable to add a code sample - What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Routing Api for getting distance, travel time and numerous other information for a given mode of transport. You can call the routing rest api from your macro (VBA).

Comment: OK, I have the App ID and App Code from Here. As I examine the code examples at <https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-constructing.html> (Thanks donPablo), I see they are expecting gps coordinates. My data as all street addresses.

Comment: You can use the geocoder api to get gps coordinates out of street addresses.